# Angular Reactive Forms and input [type=color] gives warning when initialized with empty string or null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I get this warning :

```
The specified value "" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers.
```

Here's the code :

```
<input type="color" [formControl]="fcBackgroundColor">
```

where fcBackgroundColor is :

```
fcBackgroundColor = new FormControl('');
```

or

```
fcBackgroundColor = new FormControl();
```

It's just a warning, but what's the right way to initialize the input control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MDN input type color value must always be a DOMString which contains a 7-character string specifying an RGB color in hexadecimal format. The value is never in any other form, or empty.

So its better you give a default value and process.

Answer (score 0):

As per  tag:-

The  defines a color picker.

The default value is #000000 (black). The value must be in seven-character hexadecimal notation.

So in order to use with formcontrol

```
fcBackgroundColor = new FormControl('#ff0000');
```

instead of #ff0000 can provide the color to use

Answer (score 0):

For me its helping not only use formGroup.reset alone:

```
this.formGroup.reset(
{
    fontColorMain: '#000000' // = input type="color" needs to be set, otherwise warning?
}
);
```